# Dart equivalent of long?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the equivalent of java's **long** datatype in dart ? should  **int** or **long** be used?

Comment: We can use BigInt for Long

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[In Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **long**: The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^64-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support arithmetic operations for unsigned long.

[In Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#built-in-types):

> int
>   Integer values no larger than 64 bits, depending on the platform. On the Dart VM, values can be from -2^63 to 2^63 - 1. Dart that’s compiled to JavaScript uses JavaScript numbers, allowing values from -2^53 to 2^53 - 1.

So, you can exactly use `int` in Dart for the equivalent of `long` in Java. But beware of the caveat when compiled to JavaScript.

Comment: Even for short can we have to use int?

Comment: @Uday Correct. There's no `short` in Dart.

Comment: Thanks Dart for the simplicity.

Comment: @Sos simplicity comes with a price. Representing eg pixels as 64 bits/pixel is twice the memory usage of Java or eight times the memory usage for monochrome images ... or you 'manually' pack/unpack stuff.