# How to get Max Long value in dart

Tags: dart

Is there a way to get this in dart (*java example*):

```
Math.min(Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a constant for max/min int/double value in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429660/is-there-a-constant-for-max-min-int-double-value-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, there is no direct representation of the **Long** data type. Both the **Short** and **Long** data types in Java are covered in the Dart **int** data type. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138892/dart-equivalent-of-long/57139327) for more clarity.